# Calculating based on Row and Column Values

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a very strange and complicated question and I am not even sure how to describe it, but I will try my best.

I am looking at roll-call data.  The columns of my data are individual roll-calls votes for a legislature.  The first row is the policy area for a roll-call (the policy areas are coded as "R", "G", "W", and "B") vote and all remaining rows indicate an individual legislator and how they voted on a roll-call vote.  Observations coded as 9 indicate a missing legislator.  A value of 1 means the legislator voted yes and a value of 2 means they voted no.

I am trying to examine a subset of roll call votes and determined if the legislators are missing the votes strategically.  Specifically, I am exploring whether the legislator voted for either the previous roll-call or the following roll-call vote.  For instance I have the following data:

```
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7   V8    V9    V10
Issu  R     G     G     W     R     G     R    B     R      G
Leg1  1     9     1     9     9     1     2    1     1      2   
Leg2  9     2     1     9     9     9     1    2     1      2
Leg3  1     1     1     1     9     2     1    9     1      2
```

First, I want to examine all "Iss" or policy area votes that are not equal to G (if they are coded as R, W, or B does not matter).

Second, I want to examine all individual legislator's votes on those roll-calls.  Specifically, I want to examine whether they missed a vote on a non-G roll-call (again, missing votes are coded as 9).

Next, I would like to create two scores based on the missing roll-calls (coded as 9) for all non-G roll-calls.  The scores indicate if the legislator also missed the previous or following vote (regardless of the policy area).  The first score is if they missed either the previous OR following vote.  The second score is where they missed the vote before AND after.  I would like to add these scores up for all roll-call votes (for non-G roll-calls).  If a member did not miss the roll call vote on a non-G, then that individual roll-call would contribute a value of 0 to their total score.  If they missed that individual roll-call (e.g. they received a value of 9), but were present for both the previous and following roll-call vote, then that individual roll-call would contribute a value of 0 to their scores.

For instance, in the above example, I would have the following two scores for the three legislators

```
     Or Score    And Score
Leg1   2          0
Leg2   1          1
Leg3   0          0
```

Legislator 1 would get a value of 2 for the "or" score because for V4 (which they received a 9 for) they missed the following roll-call and for V5 (which they also received a 9 for) they missed the previous roll-call.  Legislator 2 would get a value of 1 for "or" Score  because for V4 they missed the following score.  For the "And" score, Legislator 2 would receive a value of 1 because for V5 they missed both the prior and following roll-call vote (e.g. three 9's).  Finally, Leg 3 would receive a value of zero for both scores because while they missed votes, they voted for both the previous and following votes.

My question is the following, is there a way in R to calculate the "Or" Score and the "And" Score?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am not sure how to even proceed tackling this issue considering there is so many conditional relationships.  Would a loop be best?  Again, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question and I think I've seen similar question on SO. Suggest you search first.

Comment: Shouldn't legislator 2 get an OR scored since he missed V5 but also missed  either V4 or V6? If not, this complicates the boolean logic. An AND should automatically count as an OR.

Comment: Yes, you are correct legislator 2 should get an OR score.  Thank you so much!  (BTW, no this is not homework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, if you do want `or` to be inclusive of `and`, do the following:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(vote = c(1:10), t(dat))
dat %>% 
  melt(measure.vars = paste0("Leg",1:3)) %>% 
  rename(issue = Issu, legislator = variable, result = value) %>%
  filter(issue != "G") %>%
  group_by(legislator) %>%
  summarize(or = sum(result == 9 & 
                       (lag(result,1) == 9 | lead(result == 9)),
                     na.rm = T),
            and = sum(result == 9 & 
                        lag(result,1) == 9 & 
                        lead(result,1) == 9, 
                      na.rm = T))
```

If you want the NAND logic that you express in your question 
you should replace the `or` variable in the `summarize` function with 
the following:

```
or = sum(result == 9 & 
           (lag(result,1) == 9 | lead(result == 9)) & 
           !(result == 9 & 
               lag(result,1) == 9 & 
               lead(result,1) == 9)
```

The output of the second snippet will be

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  legislator    or   and
      <fctr> <int> <int>
1       Leg1     2     0
2       Leg2     1     1
3       Leg3     0     0
```

**Your data:** (please post the output of `dput` next time)

```
dat <- read.table(text = "     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7   V8    V9    V10
Issu  R     G     G     W     R     G     R    B     R      G
           Leg1  1     9     1     9     9     1     2    1     1      2   
           Leg2  9     2     1     9     9     9     1    2     1      2
           Leg3  1     1     1     1     9     2     1    9     1      2")
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is what I needed!

Comment: You're welcome @Dyllan. An upvote is always appreciated if the answer is worthy.